# GCloud Service Account cant access bucket even though he has role storage-object-admin

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a *service account* in GCloud *project A* and a *bucket* in GCloud *project B*.

In *project B* I have assigned **storage object admin** to the service account of *A* and the output of permissions in the cloud bucket console is correct too:
[image]

But still I get the following error when trying to access the *bucket in project B* from within a GCloud function *in project A*:

```
403 GET https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/my****bucket?projection=noAcl&prettyPrint=false:
exp-sa@projectA.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access
to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.
```

I cant stop thinking I am missing something really trivial here.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Ok I just used the wrong role apparently.
I though because I was just writing to the bucket Object Admin would be fine but because my code used

`bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)`

before writing it was not enough. I replaced `Storage Object Admin` with `Storage Admin` and now it is working.

Comment: Is there a  reason you did not select the answer from @boredabdel? You implemented his recommendation.

Comment: @JohnHanley No, I found this out on my own and when I posted my answer this question still had zero replies

Answer (score 2):

Storage Object Admin allows you to manage objects in a Bucket but not the bucket themselves.

Storage Admin has the storage.buckets.get permission which allows you to select a bucket.

One trick i use is lookup the pre-defined roles permissions. Navigate to the console > IAM > Roles > Search for the role and select it, on the right side you should have a full list of permissions